# Create User Account profile creates error Undefined index: location_type_id in CRM_Dedupe_BAO_Rule

Tags: profile, user-account

Drupal 7.59
Civi 4.7.27
Webform 4.17
Webform CiviCRM Integration 4.20

We are in the process of switching over from WordPress to Drupal for our CMS.

With the /user/register, when you click Create Account it does create a Drupal User and a Civi  Contact. However you get the following error message.

Notice: Undefined index: location_type_id in CRM_Dedupe_BAO_Rule->sql() (line 96 of */sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/BAO/Rule.php).

Where do I edit this form to change the location type (I am assuming it is the address that is mislabled)?[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify please - you talke about /user/register (which is not a drupal webform but a core drupal form) but you also talk about webform_civicrm. If you really mean user/register then this should be a Civi Profile and that is where you would edit the Location Type

Comment: This form is the User Login block. But it does have a Civi component to it. I assumed the Civi part was added with the CiviCRM Webform Integration. But maybe that is not the case. When I click configure on the block, that does not give me any edit options for the CiviProfile. I looked in Profiles and I did not see anything there that seemed connected to this block. I added some screenshots to my original question, hopefully this helps clarify what I am looking at.

Comment: I expect you have a Profile called "Name and Home Address" - if not someone has done something complicated instead of 'going with the flow' is my best guess

Comment: You are correct. It is the Profile "Name and Home Address" But I do not see anything there to edit that would assign the Location Type. Any ideas what I need to do to make this error message go away?

Comment: have a look by 'edit' on eg 'Street' and there you should be able to specify the location type of 'street'

Comment: converted comments to an Answer - hopefully you will give it a Tick and/or +1 so SE knows this has been answered

Answer (score 1):

Since you talk about /user/register (which is not a drupal webform but a core drupal form) then this should be a Civi Profile and that is where you would edit the Location Type.

Your screenshot shows you have a Profile called "Name and Home Address" -

have a look for 'edit' on one of the fields in the Profile eg 'Street' and there you should be able to specify the location type of 'street'

Comment: This has to be the right spot. And yes, when I click Edit with each field, I can see where to edit the Location Type. But all of the address fields are set to location type Home. The phone is set to Primary. I thought maybe that is the one that was triggering the error so I changed it to home. But it still throws the error. Any other ideas?

Comment: We did just import and convert our database from WordPress. is it possible that something did not convert correctly? If so, where would I look? I have compared "Name and Address" and all the fields to the WordPress site, everything seems to be the same.

Comment: Your error is talking about a dedupe rule isn't it? CRM_Dedupe_BAO_Rule - not sure why that might be related but also it is only a NOTICE not a Warning or an Error.

Comment: you could take a look in uf_field for those fields on the Profile (uf_group) ID in case anything leaps out as odd but don't see why a migrate would cause this issue - maybe the 'notice' was always happening? have you checked your error log for other errors?

Comment: ie confirm the location_type_id for the fields all make sense there

Comment: Good Point, yes, I am getting the same message in my debug log on our WordPress version.

Comment: Yes, I had already looked at the uf_field and uf_group. But I looked again now. I do not see anything there that looks odd.  I also looked at the CRM_Dedupe_BAO_Rule Line 96. But nothing  seems odd there either.

Comment: In the Name and Home Address Civi Profile:

I disabled all the fields, created a user and I did not get the warning message
I enabled the Street Address field, created a user and the warning message was there
I disabled the Street Address and enabled all the others, created a user and had no warning message
I looked at the civicrm_uf_field table and everything looked the same for Street Address as the others. I changed Street Address to Supplemental Address and created a new field for Street Address with location type of Home. Created a user I still got the warning message.

Comment: Continued from above comment:  I again compared this new entry in civicrm_uf_field and everything looked right. Just to test again, I disabled the Street Address field and again created a user and I did not get the warning message.

Comment: When creating a Field within a Profile, what table(s) make up the dropdown list where you select Address name, Addressee, Street Address, City, etc?  Maybe there is something there that makes Street Address different???

Comment: well sleuthed - but have nothing to offer as to why Street Address field is misbehaving esp if i assume this is the Core field and not something you or others whipped up for some reason

Comment: fyi - since we seem to agree this is just civicrm profiles you should be able to compare this with one of the demo sites.